# Error -505 when installing/updating cordova app on android

Tags: android, cordova

Some of our users has ran into this error when trying to install/update our app from the play store. 
When checking locally using adb install, the error seems to be `"INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER".`

The solution people suggest [here](https://github.com/kotmyrevich/analytics-issues/issues/784) is usually changing the AndroidManifest.xml or the gradle build file, but we can't do that because these file are autogenerated in the cordova build process. Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a (new) known bug in android build tools.
Your AndroidManifest.xml contains something like this following:
`<provider android:authorities="com.google.android.gms.measurement.google_measurement_service" ...`

Now the issue is that `android:authorities` is unique per device. The bug in the build tools is that it defaults this value to `com.google...` rather than `${myapp-id}.google...`.

To fix that, the following workaround was suggested at [the bug page](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10014):
Add a `build-extras.gradle` file to platforms/android/ with the following content:

`def manifest = new XmlSlurper().parse(file("AndroidManifest.xml")) 
android.defaultConfig.applicationId manifest.@package.text()`

Comment: have any idea why this happens to begin with?

Comment: great! so based on your impressive stackoverflow score I assume you're familiar with the concept of approving the answer that worked. All for the good of the community :)